# mglearn.plots.plot_2d_separator (eps=0.5) , what is that,"eps"?

Tags: python

Im' learning Python from the book,"introduction to Machine learning with Python"

In the book, the function below is used.

But i don't understand how the parameter"X" is worked and the necessity of the parameter "eps".

can you help me,please?

```
def plot_2d_classification(classifier, X, fill=False, ax=None, eps=None,
                           alpha=1, cm=cm3):
    # multiclass
    if eps is None:
        eps = X.std() / 2.

    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()

    x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - eps, X[:, 0].max() + eps
    y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - eps, X[:, 1].max() + eps
    xx = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, 1000)
    yy = np.linspace(y_min, y_max, 1000)

    X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(xx, yy)
    X_grid = np.c_[X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()]
    decision_values = classifier.predict(X_grid)
    ax.imshow(decision_values.reshape(X1.shape), extent=(x_min, x_max,
                                                         y_min, y_max),
              aspect='auto', origin='lower', alpha=alpha, cmap=cm)
    ax.set_xlim(x_min, x_max)
    ax.set_ylim(y_min, y_max)
    ax.set_xticks(())
    ax.set_yticks(())
```

Comment: `eps` here is a small number that would guarantee that the function won't plot some meaningless data, in case when `X[:, 0].min() == X[:, 0].max()`, in which case for example `xx` would contain all zeros and all the further results won't be any useful/correct

Comment: It's typical in programming to also add a small `eps` to a denominator (if you ever compute some division). Because if it happens that your denominator is zero, then the subsequent computations will give NaNs and infinities, instead of any meaningful numbers (especially loss in Machine Learning)

Answer (score 0):

I think eps is an element per square. It determines how compact your data entire are. as you go on increasing the value of eps all your data points get clustered into a single point.